# How to put @nickname at the comments?

Tags: support, comments, display-names, autocomplete

Is it possible to enter `@nickname` in comments, automatically? Or is one just supposed to write out the names letter by letter?

Comment: Tab completion.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: But only when the `@name` is actually needed. When you posted your comment, for example, you would not have been able to complete or even use `@klm123` in your comment box, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why should I?  It will always notify the post owner.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: exactly. But if you were expecting to use the name *anyway* (say you were not familiar with how this all worked), then no autocompletion would be available.

Comment: Ma ... so here I don't see autocompletion => I don't need to use your name, Martijn Pieters?

Comment: Just type @m, then press <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: @klm123: type `@`, then `m`, then you'll see my name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, great! Thank you!

Comment: @klm123: again, this only works when the name is available for pinging. You cannot ping Jeff Atwood or Jon Skeet from comments here, because they haven't participated here, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@names` autocomplete **only** when you actually need to use them.

If the auto-completion box doesn't appear after typing `@` and the first character of a name, then the `@name` is *not* needed. Either you are addressing the OP, or trying to address someone that is not nameable in a comment.

See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for when naming someone with the `@name` syntax is needed. When you are talking directly with the OP on their question and noone else has as yet commented, for example, `@name` name completion is not available because you don't need to use that syntax to notify the author.

There is one exception to this; you *can* name an editor of your post in comment, but the name will not be available for auto-completion. E.g. if I were to edit your question, you can use `@MartijnPieters` in a comment and I would be notified, but you'd have to type out my name yourself.